# Image is missing required "src" property. Make sure you pass "src" in props to the `next/image` component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im making a Facebook Clone and im getting this error when I want to get the profile picture of the account that log in and show it in my sidebar so he can log out in his profile picture.

The error im getting

> ```
> is Image is missing required "src" property. Make sure you pass "src" 
> in props to the `next/image` component.
> ```

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { ChevronDownIcon, SearchIcon, ViewGridIcon, ChatIcon, BellIcon } from '@heroicons/react/outline'
import { FlagIcon, PlayIcon, HomeIcon, ShoppingCartIcon, UserGroupIcon } from '@heroicons/react/outline'
import HeaderIcon from "./HeaderIcon"
import { signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react"


function header() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  return (
    <div className="sticky top-0 z-50 bg-white flex items-center p-2 lg:px-5 shadow-md">
        {/*Left*/}
        <div className="flex items-center">
            <Image 
            src="https://links.papareact.com/5me"   
            width={40} 
            height={40}
            layout="fixed"
            />
            <div className="flex ml-2 items-center rounded-full bg-gray-100 p-2">
                <SearchIcon className="h-6 text-gray-600"/>
                <input className='hidden md:inline-flex ml-2 items-center bg-transparent outline-none placeholder-gray-500 flex-shrink' type="text" placeholder="Search Facebook" />
            </div>
        </div>

        {/*Center*/}
        <div className="flex justify-center flex-grow">
          <div className="flex space-x-6 md:space-x-2">
            <HeaderIcon active Icon= {HomeIcon} />
            <HeaderIcon Icon= {FlagIcon} />
            <HeaderIcon Icon= {PlayIcon} />
            <HeaderIcon Icon= {ShoppingCartIcon} />
            <HeaderIcon Icon= {UserGroupIcon} />
          </div>
        </div>
        {/*Right*/}
        <div className="flex items-center sm:space-x-2 justify-end">
          {/*Profile*/}
            
            <Image 
             onClick={signOut()}
             className="rounded-full cursor-pointer"
             src={session?.user?.image}
             width={40}
             height={40}
             layout="fixed"
            />

            <p className="whitespace-nowrap font-semibold pr-3">Dariend Del Cid</p>
            <ViewGridIcon className="icon" />
            <ChatIcon className="icon" />
            <BellIcon className="icon" />
            <ChevronDownIcon className="icon" />
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}


export default header
```

At the moment I already try to delete the session, restart the server and try again but at the moment I press Log in with facebook throws this error. I did that thinking the profile picture of the user is not loading up but still dosnt work for me.

Comment: Have you tried to display the image in the normal html image tag ```<img/> ``` ? what was the result?

Comment: @Amr Thats work but not perfect. Now the problem is when I log in and show my home page with the sidebar my profile picture show but log me out automatically and send me to the login page. Im getting this error to **error - unhandledRejection: ReferenceError: window is not defined**

Comment: @Amr I tried to delete the `onClick={signOut()}` and works, its showing me my profile picture but now I dont have the log out option on the img

Comment: @Amr Hi, the <img/> tag works fine, ty for that. I fixed the next problem with `onClick={() => signOut()}`. Can u explain me why the <Image /> hook dosnt work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The Next image comes from

```
<Image 
  onClick={signOut()}
  className="rounded-full cursor-pointer"
  src={session?.user?.image}
  width={40}
  height={40}
  layout="fixed"
/>
```

The culprit is session?.user?.image as it's undefined at the time of execution.
Try wrapping it with a safeguar

```
 {
        session?.user?.image && (
          <Image 
            onClick={signOut()}
            className="rounded-full cursor-pointer"
            src={session?.user?.image}
            width={40}
            height={40}
            layout="fixed"
          />
      )
    }
```